# Zend app on nginx returns blank page with CONNECTION_ERROR

Tags: php, nginx, zend-framework

I am trying to set up a dev server that is a copy of production. There is PHP/Zend application installed there and served by nginx web server. I have configured nginx and the app. But when connecting to the app I am getting empty page with this text only "CONNECTION_ERROR".

You can see it here.
http://... not any more :)

The problem is that nginx error.log says nothing. And access.log shows this:

`[17/Nov/2020:20:15:56 +0000] "GET /archipelago/index/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0"`

Application log has no information at all. So it seems like the CONNECTION_ERROR is not returned by the application. So where is this from???!!!

Can anybody give any hint how to debug this? Maybe nginx conf will help?

app.conf:

```
location /archipelago {
alias /opt/bitnami/archipelago/www/public;
if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
}

rewrite (.*) /archipelago/index.php?$args;
location ~ /archipelago/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /opt/bitnami/archipelago/www/public/$1;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/php-fpm.conf";
    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/protect-hidden-files.conf";
}
}
```

php-fpm.conf:

```
index index.html index.htm $yii_bootstrap;

set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

location ~ \.php {
fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

#let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
    set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
}

fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

#PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
}
```

Comment: don't you have an php-fpm running somewhere as well? is this a dockerized environment?

Comment: It is not dockerized (as fa as I understand the term).
I don't think there is another php-fpm. How do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

However strange it seems, the CONNECTION_ERROR was an issue with DB access. :)

It is still hard to imagine why this was not recorded in the application log! All that the application returned was html with this CONNECTION_ERROR.

You may think the DB access should be the first to check if you see this error but I was sure the DB user was correctly. Still not sure why DB is not accepting it.